# Gnuplot problems with fitting data

Tags: compiler-errors, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I have to fit some peaks with a Gaussian function (bg is the background)

```
bg45(x) = a0 + a1*x

k4(x) = (x-x4)/w4

Gauss_r4(x) = A4*exp(-log(2)*k4(x)**2)
Cauchy_r4(x) = A4/(1 + k4(x)**2)

pV4(x) = alpha*Gauss_r4(x) + (1-alpha)*Cauchy_r4(x)
```

I define the initial fitting parameters as:

```
alpha = 0
beta = 0

A4 = 0.71
x4 = 4.28
w4 = 0.49 

a0 = -5.67 
a1 = 0.51
```

Then I fit like this:

```
fit [3.68:5.45] f45(x) filename u 1:2 via x4,A4,w4,a0,a1
```

I get the plot that is correct with the fitting function that is quite perfect but when I open the .dat file with the parameters found, they are totally wrong.

```
#id  r4      r4e    A4  A4e   w4      w4e
 0  4.186   0.002   4.1 0.0  0.615   0.005
```

The amplitude (which is the height of the peak A4) should be around 1 and not 4. 
Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: from where do you get or how do you generate this `.dat` file? Is it the default `fit.log` file? This would look differently than your `.dat`. If the plot of the fit is fine the `fit.log` should contain the correct values.

Comment: The lines of code you provided do not match each other, e.g. you use f45(x) for fitting, but haven't defined it anywhere. Also, beta isn't used anywhere.

Anyway, the value of a Gaussian at its maximum isn't 1, but is dependent on its width. The broader the Gaussian, the lower the maximum. Therefore it is absolutely correct that the value of your scaling factor "amplitude" is not equal to the height.